# Ping high when streaming (Streamlabs OBS)

Tags: streaming, twitch

I've tested to stream a couple of times today, and my ping is going up to 150 on Discord.

My internet speed is 10mb/s download and 1mb/s upload.
I've watched Youtube videos on people saying to start at 2500 bitrate, but I decided to lower it. I've done that multiple times from 2500, so now it's at 1000 bitrate and still doing it.

I don't want to go too low, because I don't know how much bitrate is a good quality on the stream.

Comment: Streaming requires a really good internet connection; 1mbps isn't going to cut it, unless it's extremely low quality.

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the same case as you (1Mb Upload) so I'm speaking from experience here.

It's hard to stream at that speed. I've blocked my bitrate to 800 for a 480p output image.

Still, if I do a fast movement (like spinning the camera around the character), it gets blurry.

On top of that, multiplayer has lots of lag spikes (tried with Dark Souls 3 which is peer to peer, could be different with a dedicated server game).

What I would advise is either :

- Get a better connection
- Stick to offline recording when doing multiplayer
- Stick to slow moving / 2D games

To end on a more positive point, even if your stream is blurry, when Twitch transforms it into a VOD, it gets a little bit nicer / some of the blurryness goes away.